# Can I determine the number of sub-directories in a directory using `ls -l`?

Tags: filesystems, hard-link

When displaying directories using `ls -l`, their number of links (the second field in the output) is at least two: one for the dir name and one for `.`

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -l
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  2 user   wheel  512  4 oct 14:02 foo
```

Is it safe to always assume that the number of links above 2 corresponds to the number of subdirectories in this dir (`..` links) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *usually* true on unix systems that the number of links to a directory is the number of subdirectories plus 2. However there are cases where this is not true:

- Some unices allow hard links to directories. Then there will be more than 2 links that do not correspond to subdirectories.
- There are filesystems where directories do not have entries for `.` and `..`. The [GNU find manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Directories) mentions some examples in the discussion of its `-noleaf` option (which disables an optimization that assumes that `.` and `..` exist in all directories): “CD-ROM or MS-DOS filesystems or AFS volume mount points”

An almost reliable way to count the number of subdirectories (it may still fail if a file name contains a newline character) is

```
$(($(LC_ALL=C ls -la /path/to/directory | grep '^d' | wc -l) - 2)
```

A more reliable way uses shell globs `*/` and `.*/`; as usual handling the case where the pattern doesn't match is a bit of a pain (except in bash and zsh where you can turn on the `nullglob` option).

Answer (score 2):

You could try with:

```
ls -l |grep ^d | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way to count subdirectories (non-recursively) in Bash:

```
(
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
printf '%s\000' */ | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c  # wc counts null bytes
)
```

Because each file name is being terminated by an ASCII NUL character, this should work correctly even if a file name contains a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything in the [documentation](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/ls.1.asp#Long_Output_Format) that confirms that the number of links will always be +2 on the number of subdirectories.

But, to find the correct ammount, use:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1  -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
```

Or if you have to use `ls -l`, see the other answer.

Comment: I think you meant `-type d`, but: 1. this requires GNU find; 2. you need to subtract 1 for the starting directory (or pass `-mindepth 1`).

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `ls` for this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Here's one way which works with *all* filenames, even those containing newlines, because it prints only a newline character instead of the filename:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

Edit: The current version doesn't result in any warnings, because `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` should be before `-type` (the directory tree is pruned before checking for directories, to save time).