# wc - setting a terminating character

Tags: ls, utilities, options, wc

I've got that far: `wc --files0-from=FILE` lets one get the word count of a list of files. Each entry in this list mus be terminated with an ASCII NUL character.

**Question**: A way to set a terminating character, such as NUL by hand, or something else? I found this here [quoted from the `info wc` output]:

> … produce a list of ASCII NUL terminated file names is with GNU `find', using its`-print0' predicate.

I found somebody saying the [each file name is being terminated by an ASCII NUL character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/can-i-determine-the-number-of-sub-directories-in-a-directory-using-ls-l/20858#20858). Is it right that this fits to, say the output of `ls`?
I know, [one shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but writing the output into a file to be read by `wc` another time would be nice.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/can-i-determine-the-number-of-sub-directories-in-a-directory-using-ls-l/20858#20858. In this answer, each filename is terminated by a NUL because of the `printf` command. 
`printf '%s\000' *` takes the files in the current directory (thanks to '*') and prints each one appending a \000 (a NUL character) after it.

Comment: `wc --files0-from=<(find . -type f -print0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls` ends each filename with a newline (`\n`) and not a NUL (`\0`) (if its standard output is not a terminal).

A way to list the files in the current directory, using NUL as a separator, is:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -print0`.

This will match the files starting with a period too. To ignore them, use:

`find . -maxdepth 1 \! -name '.*' -print0`

Others ways could be:

```
ls | tr '\n' '\0'
```

or

```
printf '%s\0' *
```

As noted by @ChrisDown in his comment, only the `find` and the `printf` options will do the job correctly if you have file names containing `\n` in the current directory. If this is not your case (in fact, I wonder if there really are people using newlines in file names out there), the three are equivalent.

Comment: Note that `ls | tr '\n' '\0'` and `find . -maxdepth 1 \! -name '.*' -print0` are not strictly equivalent as the former will mangle existing newlines that are not terminators: http://sprunge.us/MMYj

Comment: If you want to exclude the current directory but include hidden files, use `-mindepth 1`.

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, you're right. `find` is the only command that will function well with all valid filenames. The `ls` solution will work in most of the cases, but not _all_.
@l0b0 Great! Thank you for the `-mindepth` precision.